# Unable to paste file name in terminal using mouse

Tags: command-line, mplayer

Hi Iam a newbie to linux .If some body help me trouble shoot the below problem that will be greatful .I now only changed my gnome desktop to xfce . While playing video in terminal using mplayer Iam unable copy paste video files . mplayer showing this message

```
jai@dhcppc0:~$ mplayer file:///home/jai/Total%20Siyapaa%20%20Title%20Song%20%20%20by%20ali%20jafar-GKr6rCNlSuM.mp4
MPlayer svn r34540 (Debian), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing file:///home/jai/Total%20Siyapaa%20%20Title%20Song%20%20%20by%20ali%20jafar-GKr6rCNlSuM.mp4.
File not found: '/home/jai/Total%20Siyapaa%20%20Title%20Song%20%20%20by%20ali%20jafar-GKr6rCNlSuM.mp4'
Failed to open file:///home/jai/Total%20Siyapaa%20%20Title%20Song%20%20%20by%20ali%20jafar-GKr6rCNlSuM.mp4.


Exiting... (End of file)
```

I don't know how to copy file name instead of this %20 %20 thing .
Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the name of the file?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

1. `%20` represents a space (). In general, spaces should be avoided in file names, because they can cause problems for some programs. Therefore you should rename your file and replace  with `_`.
2. It is better to give the filename to a command with the direct path. Judging from the command you posted, I believe this is `/home/jai/Total Siyapaa Title Song by ali jafar-GKr6rCN1SuM.mp4`

In summary, after renaming your file, typing

```
mplayer ~/Total_Siyapaa_Title_Song_by_ali_jafar-GKr6rCN1SuM.mp4
```

in your terminal should work.

Comment: No need to replace the spaces with underscores, just put the filename in double or single quotes, or escape the spaces with backslashes. E.g. `~/"file name"`, `~/'file name'` or `~/file\ name`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all whitespace and the `file://` part of the command.
The terminal can interpret whitespace as %20; same thing with some search engines.

You can escape whitespace by placing the location of the file in quotes, like this:

```
mplayer "/home/jai/Total Siyapaa  Title Song   by ali jafar-GKr6rCNlSuM.mp4"
```

You can also replace the `/home/jai/` part with `~/` - it's basically shorthand for your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know stands `%20` for the space. So you can write an escaped space instead.

This should do it for you:

```
file:///home/jai/Total\ Siyapaa\ \ Title\ Song\ \ \ by\ ali\ jafar-GKr6rCNlSuM.mp4
```

Here you can get more info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

But I recommend you to use `_` instead for filenames like [Wayne_Yux](https://askubuntu.com/users/420599/wayne-yux) said.

Answer (score 0):

all you are trying to do is to open a video file from cli using mplayer and I am wondering what so difficult in doing that if you have just checked the man page or searched on internet:

```
  http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html
```

Even without the help of documentation one would straight follow the logic and perform:

```
  mplayer /path/to/file-to-play.mp4
```

In addition the output speak by itself "File not found:"

It would be easier for you is to perform:

```
  cd /path/to/where/mp4/located
  mplayer file-to-play.mp4
```

Or use TAB key to let bash help you in auto complete what and where you are trying to go.

And if you have fancy names with special chars etc, all you have to do is to rename the file by giving a short name if you don't know how to use bash/shell.

In the other end all you are trying to do is to open and mp4 file in your local home directory from what i see. Wouldn't be that easier just to click on the file and the system will spark it up for you in auto?

What is you purpose of starting a video file in shell?

Sorry but all this questions are coming naturally when you see such post here. If you are aiming to learn shell command line that is another story.